# How can I filter a field from a Many To Many relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the following tables scheme:

```
Table_1
    Name
    Field_A
    Field_B

User_Table
    Name
    Field_C
    Field_D

Table_3
    FK Table_1
    FK User_Table
    Field_E
```

All the relations work properly. I need to do something like this:

```
Table1.where(table_3.FK_Table_1: @current_user)
```

Basically, I just want to show the items that belong to the `@current_user`. I'm using my serializer to get all the `Field_E` that belongs to `Table_1`, but when I have 2 same items with the same `Table_1`, obviously it overwrites the value of `Field_E`. I want it to return all the items that are in `Table_1` that also are from the `@current_user`

My current user is working correctly, so no worries with that. I just need help in how to achieve the `where` statement.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are your models set up? From what you're describing, you need to specify that you're joining `Table1` and `Table3`, and filtering by current user. Something like:

```rb
class Foo
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :user
end

# Joining and filtering
Foo.joins(:bars).where(bars: { user: @current_user })
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm doing, but the `where` statement is giving me some issues

Comment: Can you give us more details? What is the output?

Comment: The output is `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: falta una entrada para la tabla`

Comment: It was an issue with plurals, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out more about the `has_many :through` association from [RoR guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class Table1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :table3s
  has_many :users, through: :table3s
end

class Table3 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table1
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :table3s
  has_many :table1s, through: :table3s
end
```

Then you can call `@current_user.table1s` to get all records in table1 that belongs to `@current_user`.

Note that using a join table (table3, in your case) implies a many-to-many relationship (1 table1 can belong to many users, 1 user can have many table1s).